# Daily reminder email workflow creation in SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow

I need to create a daily remainder for current actor of my form.

I'm struggling with logic how to perform daily variable. Can you Help ?

Thank you,

Comment: Refer this link. this will help you - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79271/workflow-to-send-reminder-mail-weekly-if-task-not-completed

Answer (score 0):

You can loop under your condition and use Delay (Duration Time to wait before checking again).

For **Daily** use `TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`

For more details you can check this response : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224570/57592